# Query Jetpack Subscriber Stats Shown in Admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

[image showing subscriber stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugStN.png)
Is there a way to query the numbers shown on this page so I can include them in the template of a stats page?

get_stats_csv doesn't appear to carry this information, so I'm at a total loss...

The intention is to just include this number on my stats page so it can be seen by advertisers, etc.